# Unable to open the frame in the same page

Tags: php, frame

I am using frame This is my code so far for `middlereports.php`:

```
<frameset cols="21%,79%,0%" frameborder="0" framespacing="5" border="0">
  <frame src="reportstree.php" id="frTree" name="frTree">
  <frame src="generatereportdetails.php" id="frDesc" name="frDesc">
  <frame src="UntitledFrame-3" name="frHidden" id="frHidden">
</frameset>
```

now I am calling this page Here in my topui.php

```
<?php
{
    echo "<a href=\"middlereports.php\" target=\"frMiddle\">";
}
?>
```

I want to open this page in same window in topui.php but i m unable to do that

Comment: @Prisoner:) i don't no what is it? i m new one in the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no target `frMiddle` in your frameset. Did you mean `frDesc`?

Comment: :) by using my coding my page middlereports.php open in new window i want to call in the same window below my topui.php

Comment: remove the `target="frMiddle"` - if you give a target that does not exist, it opens a new window.

Comment: :) Bro i am using this and now my page open in the same window but i want my topui.php page also shown .... which is invisible after click

Comment: Then you should know the name of the frame you want your content to appear in, and put that name into the `target=""` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an iframe instead?